# different testcase example for androidTest and test folder in android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-instrumentation

Android studio is creating 2 folder androidTest and **test**. can anyone give example of testcases for both folders.

Answer (score 1):

The test/ folder will contain unit testing code that runs on your system's JVM. This is the same as plain java unit testing, so any classes that don't touch the Android framework would work great here.

The androidTest/ folder will contain instrumentation tests instead - these require a device or emulator to run. Things you'd test with it are Activities, Services, Providers, etc.

For examples on both, you can refer to the documentation:

- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing
- https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/samples/index.html